# Don't install dependencies when performing `setup.py test`

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to do an offline installation of a python package. As part of the installation, I run the package's tests with `python3 setup.py test`. When I run the test command, setuptools fetches all of the unsatisfied dependencies from `pypi.python.org`. However I'm providing all of the package's dependencies and if a dependency isn't satisfied, I want that to be an error -- I don't want setuptools to download dependencies for me. I'm not sure how to disable this behavior, or even how to tell it to use a different server. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so here's one way to do it. It's possibly not the most elegant and it has some downsides, but it seems to work.

Create (or modify an existing) `setup.cfg` file with the following lines:

```
[easy_install]
find_links = file:///dev/null
index_url = file:///dev/null
```

This will inform `easy_install` (which is what is operating under the hood) to not use any external pypi server.